# Given a Hamiltonian Path routine, how do I use that to determine whether or not a graph has a Hamiltonian Cycle?

Tags: java, graph

Obviously, if the graph doesn't even have a Hamiltonian Path, it doesn't have a Hamiltonian Cycle, so `if (!g.hp()) return false;` but I'm a little lost after that.

The hint given in class was to add a number of vertices. My thought was that if the graph has a Hamiltonian path before adding the vertex and adding a vertex in meant that the graph no longer had a Hamiltonian path, the original graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Of course, I'm not looking for pseudocode or code, I'd just like to be pushed in the right direction.

Edit: The Wikipedia page mentions that you can use a Hamiltonian path routine to find if it has a Hamiltonian cycle by connecting an additional vertex to every vertex in the previous graph. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way - a Hamiltonian Cycle is just a Hamiltonian Path that has an edge between the path's endpoints.  Likewise, removing any single edge from a Hamiltonian Cycle results in a Hamiltonian Path.  This means that if you were to add a vertex to the graph by connecting it to a single existing vertex via a single edge, you would still have a Hamiltonian Path in the new graph.  This would hold true no matter where you inserted that new vertex.

This also means that if there exists a vertex in the graph such that connecting it to a single new vertex with a single edge results in a new graph with no Hamiltonian Path, then that graph has no Hamiltonian Cycle (I suspect your professor wants you to prove this by contradiction, so I'll leave that up to you).  You can use that fact to create your Hamiltonian Cycle algorithm.  I know you didn't ask for psuedo code, but I'll give you some anyway:

```
boolean hc(Graph g){
    if(!g.hp()) return false;

    Vertex test = new Vertex();

    for(Vertex v : g){
        g.connect(test,v); //adds single edge between test and v
        if(!g.hp()) return false;
        g.disconnect(test,v); //removes any edges between test and v
    }

    //every test yielded a new graph with a Hamiltonian Path, therefore
    //g must have a Hamiltonian Cycle:
    return true;
}
```